# How to verify paypal account of the user?

Tags: paypal, react-native, paypal-sandbox

I am developing a react-native app which prompts our users to enter their email id registered with Paypal. Below is the flow of the payment process I am following -

The entered email id is then sent to backend server which uses your Payout Rest API ( /v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true ) endpoint to pay money to the user’s Paypal account. To provide our users a seamless payment experience, we want to make sure that the email id they have entered is registered with Paypal. To verify the entered email id, after hours of Google search, we found out about AdaptiveAccounts APIs. Now, we only want to use “AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus”  endpoint ( to verify the email id ) and then payment will be carried out by the Payout Rest APi.

We are ready to create our app on ( https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications ), but it asks to select one of the **Adaptive Payments** method ( **which we are not going to use** ).
So, can anyone please provide me a solution or a workaround for the situation?

Although I found some links on Stack Overflow which provide issues to the same problem, but they all point to the same “AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus”  endpoint. And we are again stuck with the same problem of selecting Adaptive Payment option.

Comment: The only way that you can do is via GetVerifiedStatus using Adaptive Accounts. Once you get the status, you can use the email to initiate the Payout in REST.

Comment: Agreed. But for using Adaptive Accounts, I need AppID ( provided by paypal after they have reviewed your app ). While submitting for review to get AppID, paypal asks for choosing one of Adaptive Payment method (**which we are not going to use**). Now, how to submit App for review?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to file an MTS ticket. They will help you with this.

Comment: Thank you for quick responses. I have already filed one. No reply from paypal yet.

Comment: If its not a hassle, would you mind to you share the ticket # here?